# How do i get right row in history table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table with price history:

```
| StrartDat | ProductID | Price | EndDate|
```

Table of products:

```
| ProductID | Name | quantity|...|
```

And table of orders:

```
| OrderID |ProductID | date|...|
```

Now i am trying to get list of orders but i get two rows for one product with its old price and new one (where enddate is null)

How can i escape such situation and get order with a price that a product had at date of order.

I tried this constrains but it doesn't take a orders that are linked with price where enddate is null

```
  Where EndDate > OrderCustm.Date AND StartDate <= OrderCustm.Date
```

Comment: Have new prices EndDate = null always?

Comment: yes, it is always null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can just add an explicit `NULL` condition:

```
Where StartDate <= OrderCustm.Date AND
      (EndDate > OrderCustm.Date OR EndDate IS NULL)
```